# Selenium with Edge: A exception with a `null` response

Tags: c#, selenium, microsoft-edge

I have a problem with using Selenium with Edge. I use .NET Core 3.0.

This is my simple test:

```
[Fact]
public void EdgeDriverTest1() {
    using (IWebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver()) {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
        IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
        element.SendKeys("Hello, Selenium WebDriver!");
        element.Submit();
    }
}
```

When I run it Edge window will be opened and I get the error:

> `OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException` : A exception with a `null` response
>   was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for
>   URL `http://localhost:60127/session`. The status of the exception was
>   `UnknownError`, and the message was: An error occurred while sending the
>   request

Nuget packages:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is right and this error occurs mainly because the Microsoft WebDriver version you're using doesn't match the Edge version you're using.

If you're using Edge version **prior to 18**, you can download the appropriate webdriver for your installed version of Microsoft Edge in [this link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/#downloads). If your Microsoft Edge version is **18 or higher**, you can install the appropriate webdriver version according to the ways in [this article](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/06/14/webdriver-w3c-recommendation-feature-on-demand/#Rg8g2hRfjBQQVRXy.97).