# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException when instantiating new EdgeDriver()

Tags: c#, selenium, microsoft-edge

I have a collection of xunit tests using Selenium that all run fine for Chrome and Internet Explorer.  Recently added is the need to test with Edge. After installing **Selenium.WebDriver.MicrosoftDriver** 17.17134.0, I encounter this error message:

> **A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL [http://localhost:](http://localhost:__)**{FOO}**/session. The status of the exception was UnknownError, and the message was: An error occurred while sending the request. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..**
>
> ***Note:** the port, represented above by {FOO} changes on each run, and not to any port configured anywhere in `launchSettings.json` files nor anywhere else in this solution.*

The error occurs when running tests, on the following line:

```cs
    IWebDriver result = new EdgeDriver();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Edge browser are you using? This error occurs mainly because the Microsoft WebDriver version you're using doesn't match the Edge version you're using.

If you're using **Edge Legacy version prior to 18** or **New Edge Chromium**, you can download the appropriate webdriver for your installed version of Microsoft Edge in [this link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/#downloads). If your **Edge Legacy version is 18 or higher**, you can install the appropriate webdriver version according to the ways in [this article](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/06/14/webdriver-w3c-recommendation-feature-on-demand/#Rg8g2hRfjBQQVRXy.97).

You could also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56920240/selenium-with-edge-a-exception-with-a-null-response) for the similar issue.